# error in pandas dataframe datetime comparison code?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

this is a code to compare sample data with date and give a panda dataframe such that all the dates and 2 hours of that day are marked as 1 and the rest is 0 ,I have the output below where its prompted to show just 2 hours for each day and the sample data is just 2 days whereas in actual I have 300 days

for some reason there's an error and not able to get the output

```
    import pandas as pd
    from datetime import datetime,timedelta
    # sample data
    df = pd.DataFrame({"date": [datetime(2020,10,2), datetime(2020,10,4)]})
    df_hr = pd.DataFrame({"hr": [datetime(2020,10,1,0,0) + i * timedelta(hours=1) for i in range(24*4)]})
    df_hr["flag"] = 0
    df_hr.loc[df_hr["hr"].dt.date.isin(df["date"]), "flag"] = 1
    # show the first and last hour of each day
    df_hr.loc[[0,23,24,47,48,71,72,95]]
```

this is supposed to be the output

```
                         hr  flag 
    0  2020-10-01 00:00:00     0 
    23 2020-10-01 23:00:00     0 
    24 2020-10-02 00:00:00     1 
    47 2020-10-02 23:00:00     1 
    48 2020-10-03 00:00:00     0 
    71 2020-10-03 23:00:00     0 
    72 2020-10-04 00:00:00     1 
    95 2020-10-04 23:00:00     1
```

whereas I get

```
        hr  flag
    0   2020-10-01 00:00:00 0
    23  2020-10-01 23:00:00 0
    24  2020-10-02 00:00:00 0
    47  2020-10-02 23:00:00 0
    48  2020-10-03 00:00:00 0
    71  2020-10-03 23:00:00 0
    72  2020-10-04 00:00:00 0
    95  2020-10-04 23:00:00 0
```

​

Comment: What's the `date` function here?

Comment: You might consider changing `i * timedelta(hours=1)` to just `timedelta(hours=i)`

Comment: @CollinHeist this doesn't work

Comment: @QuangHoang I've edited the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure your `isin()` is comparing against the same object types. Change your `.loc()` statement to:

```py
df_hr.loc[df_hr["hr"].dt.date.isin(df["date"].dt.date), "flag"] = 1
```

This looks at the `'hr'` column of `df_hr` as a `datetime.date` object, and then sees if that object is in the `'date'` column of `dt` *also* casted as a `date time.date` object. Works for me.